# Regex - Match all numbers until character

Tags: php, regex

Lets assume I have a string like this

```
1234hello567u8 915 kl15
```

I want to match all the numbers up until the first space (So, **12345678**)

I know I can use this: `[^\s]*` to match everything until the first space.. But how

How do i use `[^\s]*` to only match numbers?

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Comment: You need to do that in 2 steps: 1) Obtain the first chunk until the space with `^\S+`, and then 2) replace the non-digit characters with `\D+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP you can use this:

```
$re = '/\h.*|\D+/'; 
$str = "1234hello567u8 915 kl15"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
//=> 12345678
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS0oU9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is about matching a pattern but it seems like you don't know exactly pattern of your text.

I suggest you like this

1. Replace all [a-z] to "", by using

   regex: `"s/[a-z]//g"`

   output: `"12345678 915 15"`
2. Capture text you want,

   regex: `"(^\d+)"`

   output: `"12345678"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture input that skips other input in a single group.

In what ever tool, you're using make this replacement:

```
Search: \D| .*
Replace: <blank>
```

The search regex matches non digits or everything after a space (including the space).